# Why won't my code sum the value of the negative numbers in the list?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
total7 = 0
i = 0
while i <= len(given_list3) and given_list3[i] <= 0:
    total7 += givenlist3[i]
    i += 1
print(total7)
```

The code is producing a result of 0, and I want to to result in: -2 + -3 + -5 + -7 = -17

Answer (score 6):

You can use comprehension:

```py
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
output = sum(x for x in given_list3 if x < 0)
print(output) # -17
```

In your current code, you are exiting the `while` loop even before the first iteration, because the second condition `given_list3[i] <= 0` is false (since the first item `7` is greater than `0`). If you want a working version, try the following. (Also you need to use `i < len(...)`, *not* `i <= len(...)`.)

```py
given_list3 = [7, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, -2, -3, -5, -7]
total7 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(given_list3):
    if given_list3[i] <= 0:
        total7 += given_list3[i]
    i += 1
print(total7) # -17
```

Answer (score 3):

A `while` loop stops when the condition is false. So your loop stops when it gets to the first positive value. Since the first element of the list is positive, the loop doesn't do anything.

The negative condition should be `if` inside the loop.

Also, list indexes go to `len(list)-1`, so the length condition should be `<`, not `<=`.

```
while i < len(given_list3):
    if given_list3[i] <= 0:
        total7 += given_list3[i]
    i += 1
```

You should get out of the habit of looping over list indexes. Use `for-in`:

```
for item in given_list3:
    if item <= 0:
        total7 += item
```

Comment: Champion, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

**You never iterate through your while loop.**

On the first iteration `i` is `0` and the while-loop checks it's condition:

```
white 0 <= len(given_list3) and given_list3[i] < = 0:
    ...
```

`given_list3[i]` when `i` is `0` is `given_list3[0]` which is `7`. `7` is not less than or equal to `0`. The whole condition fails and the while loop is done.

The statements in the while-loop get executet as long as the condition is true. In your sample the condition is already false the first time it is checked and the statements in the while-loop never get executed.